# How to secure fastapi API endpoint with JWT Token based authorization?

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi

I am a little new to FastAPI in python. I am building an API backend framework that needs to have JWT token based authorization. Now, I know how to generate JWT tokens, but not sure how to integrate that with API methods in fast api in Python. Any pointers will be really appreciated.

Comment: You could just put it in the `cookies` or set it in the local storage by frontend.

Comment: See how it is implemented in this example app - https://github.com/nsidnev/fastapi-realworld-example-app :-)

Comment: thanks for your fast response, but I am still not sure. Just to give you more details, I am trying to generate a Microsoft AD JWT token, so I have an authority end point: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant-id>/ and I have an AD app created with audience url - api://xxxcxxxx-abb3-yyyy-34ae-15f04ce1zzzz

Now, using this, I want my Fastapi endpoints to have JWT based authorization security enabled, so that only when a valid bearer token is passed as a header to the api endpoint, only then it would given back the reponse, otherwise http 401 unauthorized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With some help from my friend and colleague, I was able to solve this problem, and wanted to share this solution with the community. This is how it looks like now:

#### Python Code ----

```
import json    
import os    
import datetime   
from fastapi import HTTPException, Header    
from urllib.request import urlopen    
from jose import jwt    
from jose import exceptions as JoseExceptions    
from utils import logger

AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.environ.get(
    'AUTH0_DOMAIN', 'https://<domain>/<tenant-id>/')

AUTH0_ISSUER = os.environ.get(
    'AUTO0_ISSUER', 'https://sts.windows.net/<tenant>/')

AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE = os.environ.get(
    'AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE', '<audience url>')

AZURE_OPENID_CONFIG = os.environ.get(
    'AZURE_OPENID_CONFIG', 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration')


def get_token_auth_header(authorization):
    parts = authorization.split()

    if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401, 
            detail='Authorization header must start with Bearer')
    elif len(parts) == 1:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401, 
            detail='Authorization token not found')
    elif len(parts) > 2:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401, 
            detail='Authorization header be Bearer token')
    
    token = parts[1]
    return token


def get_payload(unverified_header, token, jwks_properties):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(
            token,
            key=jwks_properties["jwks"],
            algorithms=jwks_properties["algorithms"],  # ["RS256"] typically
            audience=AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE,
            issuer=AUTH0_ISSUER
        )
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401, 
            detail='Authorization token expired')
    except jwt.JWTClaimsError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401, 
            detail='Incorrect claims, check the audience and issuer.')
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401, 
            detail='Unable to parse authentication token')

    return payload


class AzureJWKS:
    def __init__(self, openid_config: str=AZURE_OPENID_CONFIG):
        self.openid_url = openid_config
        self._jwks = None
        self._signing_algorithms = []
        self._last_updated = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0)
    
    def _refresh_cache(self):
        openid_reader = urlopen(self.openid_url)
        azure_config = json.loads(openid_reader.read())
        self._signing_algorithms = azure_config["id_token_signing_alg_values_supported"]
        jwks_url = azure_config["jwks_uri"]

        jwks_reader = urlopen(jwks_url)
        self._jwks = json.loads(jwks_reader.read())

        logger.info(f"Refreshed jwks config from {jwks_url}.")
        logger.info("Supported token signing algorithms: {}".format(str(self._signing_algorithms)))
        self._last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()

    def get_jwks(self, cache_hours: int=24):
        
            logger.info("jwks config is out of date (last updated at {})".format(str(self._last_updated)))
            self._refresh_cache()
        return {'jwks': self._jwks, 'algorithms': self._signing_algorithms}

jwks_config = AzureJWKS()


async def require_auth(token: str = Header(...)):
    token = get_token_auth_header(token)
   

    try:
        unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    except JoseExceptions.JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=401, 
                    detail='Unable to decode authorization token headers')

    payload = get_payload(unverified_header, token, jwks_config.get_jwks())
    if not payload:
        raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=401, 
                    detail='Invalid authorization token')

    return payload
```

I hope the community gets benefited from this!

Comment: That get_token_auth_header() function looks just like the documentation from Auth0.

Answer (score 44):

I found certain improvements that could be made to the accepted answer:

- If you choose to use the **HTTPBearer security schema**, the format of the *Authorization* header content is automatically validated, and there is no need to have a function like the one in the accepted answer,  `get_token_auth_header`. Moreover, the generated docs end up being super clear and explanatory, with regards to authentication:

[image]

- When you decode the token, you can catch all exceptions that are descendants of the class `JOSEError`, and print their message, avoiding catching specific exceptions, and writing custom messages
- Bonus: in the jwt decode method, you can specify what claims you want to ignore, given the fact you don't wanna validate them

Sample snippet:
Where ...

```
/endpoints
          - hello.py
          - __init__.p
dependency.py
main.py
```

```py
# dependency.py script
from jose import jwt
from jose.exceptions import JOSEError
from fastapi import HTTPException, Depends
from fastapi.security import HTTPAuthorizationCredentials, HTTPBearer

security = HTTPBearer()

async def has_access(credentials: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials= Depends(security)):
    """
        Function that is used to validate the token in the case that it requires it
    """
    token = credentials.credentials

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, key='secret', options={"verify_signature": False,
                                                           "verify_aud": False,
                                                           "verify_iss": False})
        print("payload => ", payload)
    except JOSEError as e:  # catches any exception
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401,
            detail=str(e))
```

```py
# main.py script
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from endpoints import hello
from dependency import has_access

app = FastAPI()

# routes
PROTECTED = [Depends(has_access)]

app.include_router(
    hello.router,
    prefix="/hello",
    dependencies=PROTECTED
)
```

```py
# hello.py script
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("")
async def say_hi(name: str):
    return "Hi " + name
```

By taking advantage of all the mentioned features, you end up building an API with security super fast :)

Comment: This is great! thank you :)

Comment: based on this answer, i've created a file on github, you guys can check and follow: https://github.com/saxsax1995/fastapi-very-first-tutorial/blob/master/auth-jwt-without-user.py

Comment: Follow-up, how can I add a front-end framework with this auth?

Answer (score 9):

Integrating it to API methods is easy with [Depends](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) and [Response Model](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/)

So let me provide an example, imagine you are deploying your ML Model, and you are going to add some security, in your case you already created the Token Part:

### TL DR

```
class User(BaseModel):
    pass
...
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
...
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)): # You created a function that depends on oauth2_scheme
    pass
...
@app.get("/users/me/models/")
async def read_own_items(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
   pass
```

### Some example

**Pydantic schemas**

```
class Url(BaseModel):
    url: str

class AuthorizationResponse(BaseModel):
    pass

class User(BaseModel):
    pass

class AuthUser(BaseModel):
    pass

class Token(BaseModel):
    pass
```

**Your app**

```
LOGIN_URL = "https://example.com/login/oauth/authorize"
REDIRECT_URL = f"{app}/auth/app"
...
@app.get("/login")
def get_login_url() -> Url:
    return Url(url=f"{LOGIN_URL}?{urlencode(some_params_here)}")

@app.post("/authorize")
async def verify_authorization(body: AuthorizationResponse, db: Session = Depends(some_database_fetch)) -> Token:
    return Token(access_token=access_token, token_type="bearer", user=User)

def create_access_token(*, data: User, expire_time: int = None) -> bytes:
    return encoded_jwt

def get_user_from_header(*, authorization: str = Header(None)) -> User: # from fastapi import Header
    return token_data   #Token data = User(**payload)

@app.get("/me", response_model=User)
def read_profile(user: User = Depends(get_user_from_header), db: Session = Depends(some_database_fetch),) -> DbUser:
    return db_user
```

### Summary of example above

1. We created a `LOGIN_URL`, then a Pydantic schema for that URL
2. Then we created `/authorize` endpoint for the backend to check it and get all it needs from the User API
3. Function for creating a simple JWT token which is  `create_access_token`
4. Through JWT token we just created, we can create a dependency `get_user_from_header` to use in some private endpoints

**Sebastian Ramirez(Creator of FastAPI)** has a great video that shows how you can add a basic auth to your app [FastAPI - Basic HTTP Auth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9K5pwb0rt8&t=1571s)

FastAPI has a great documentation about, [**oauth2-jwt**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/):

For some real world example, [**fastapi-users**](https://github.com/frankie567/fastapi-users)  has a perfect JWT authentication backend.

Comment: thanks for your fast response, but I am still not sure. Just to give you more details, I am trying to generate a Microsoft AD JWT token, so I have an authority end point: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant-id>/ and I have an AD app created with audience url - api://xxxcxxxx-abb3-yyyy-34ae-15f04ce1zzzz

Now, using this, I want my Fastapi endpoints to have JWT based authorization security enabled, so that only when a valid bearer token is passed as a header to the api endpoint, only then it would given back the reponse, otherwise http 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Ah okay, i saw your answer and comment now, but this is spesific case, you may want to update the question